# Фанат - мужской/женский род

Tags: грамотная-речь, существительные

Может ли женщина сказать или написать: "Я ваш фанат"? Или только фанатка?

Comment: @Алина Глазатова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, если речь идёт о конкретном человеке, напр. известном артисте или музыканте, в письменном виде лучше сказать "поклонница". Особенно, если вы хотите своим посланием оставить у незнакомого человека благоприятное о себе впечатление. Слово "фанат(ка)" имеет сниженный оттенок и своеобразное происхождение: исторически это гибрид английского fan (поклонник) и старого слова "фанатик", которое в русском обычно употреблялось с негативным оттенком (религиозный фанатик или человек, болезненно уверовавший в какую-то идею). Поначалу (80-е годы прошлого века) слово применялось только к футбольным болельщикам и было их неформальным самоназванием. Сейчас ситуация изменилась в сторону расширения значений этого слова, оно часто заменяет слово "поклонник" (человека и его таланта), которое, в свою очередь, в прессе стало употребляться излишне расширенно, заменяя слово "любитель", что иногда приводит к странным сочетаниям (поклонник немецких овчарок, рыбной ловли и т.п.). Поэтому сохранение культуры речи зависит и от нашего словоупотребления, порой в противостоянии тому, что предлагается журналистами или просто людьми "из телевизора".

Comment: Спасибо, я бы тоже сказала "поклонница", но спор вышел именно о слове фанат.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: фанат/фанатка.  См.:

- [Толковый словарь Ожегова](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=611.ocuzX45XO-7stg3GRBRDEp0lKR_jnPnuMKHRiAEHCPs.4efbb2ab84d8ad7a6368cbcb076aa399275c5601&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW99KUdgowt9Xuhyw5P1wAdC5B4OoApALaNQ6Y5-iwO44gwhcCrct2s2-fQPdmeWHj002HHpmYz6ahNG4QfFiggDKinYrQJZI206eRr4YCKmZa6y8xZlAUyGpJhC65TjHc25Knf8jlXhGHlERTcuRfklEkQ6Gv-_xoQb7BwafOUXPQEktxLgrE1gSTQCNHVLDGZuDSZSyI42lf9GClTFYS8Q3woCpc5NhrFw3nByh4YkOnSfpqXrsEd4w&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1Ldmtxb25KS2FnTFVCbGNMZ0FQbkwtVURQVW9rVTk0QUVzYUo1ckFRYmdEY3ViMVFveks0VV9EV0hBVGkxSWdheVNwZkhGMS1ZdFhtQkFNOWlfSG9iVmZUREpoS2J2S3MwNTA2V29DTW1la05SWFc&b64e=2&sign=e3b3a8c162358f34ae6d87e33b2c928a&keyno=0&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHtkusEOiLu3m4cVndcRMfNuguIXI6uHFKopKeimbzjngWRZvLd4jTnwfwuM6o0yjNHHvaMdg80SFpt3XGn80kZQcKIqLcxelfrYHWyJjF2YRpDQRaea1ZKD2FAZjYffyGg-M_O0bumEnLlkI8xYzRPORGfIKqtOog2f-V4QcwxWr-uZPUCS9XUQ3IsGf_HALFRIOTir0QuAOIYXEKlWU4JPzDYLox8FEgqBkJlIa961Wyv_40Lzld9aCsKdIqVJtZvmpJrp9H7c4kRsE8foA9J-Z5xbtj87gMtp7wlLJRbdR_CLqqv0TqOstn0kaPGSbHaU5VtGnpITs_9jbzWluQqtRU3FLDd6OwFdGkaMi2Fk39DTqhAi9zZEU-AE4ET8gCe4BE_NJEhjhRpJ0QACIw9rkriZJD9fv9ZUvT3MX0EQp2_tw1jG8E31QFY2KFgGILvKrA7xQH8l3I0UGn-oWyxYF9JlsAzIJwUx8r4kO0OwW5maW1njv0E_BS3PsuHbhRFZAN_W-0A8U7f5RrWRjnHkVG02HTSfkK_f3JjfvHI47puL_sMN6fqowFmqOBfJ0LQAZzwXe1Qz4EG42DjjiCo9mRE8Q8gqNENjMkrpZ7QEwRihF4nDAA_BKUdnJbBqXstaEWDAcN-E49oc4mzJubPqh7FD3Ngj6f1ndLZGhluBdKqmh4jNZNi5AVMwU3JsqONP5nMfQLs2bCbzhJbQcYHRbpi-oDH1WVstyt3MlBLRWb-osf6PJNAzPnPSLruxdU1Kvn-fWTjw00S-VcySiMKpCDY7c_KVdHPhOybY0qI_eUBsz5YcSMIN8IvnWsN2Lq8aus17PE5jgIWFimwp0wsD4q98OYbbqL0SjAFr1DIlKuLaIRjU3ep1EilODeyCM6WYV6FfM7_IzAsdCsi-l7bPDtfzyqPLV3CCTP7ZZ_KDELbHnNpU1cIOqmZK1cxyWJO8fpVtTjRX1OerZBOb40fFZIS9ZIeQ0TAA8OUYeyBAJ_SeJ2zQgMqgrrfwDXll9EZUqxIJwYKzsRiRIZ1gYqrcewUsPjcfZjWqxJVEWP5wBntcAfmKgL44oINB1wdW1CxGoKfZh1efKTLKep6BM_AJE4hIMqvLbO_T2vsPTMKKhpMNbgcYnGfSqwMXQsrpf2ejZwBNEwyDjWKwxyDcc-n9oJLJvW6NJJU_ukd4bpww2ZLxl5_yAlfogxHN9UO2VqjTd2k4M9-R8YldmO4UJrdOsw2PUyzvKXxjmD74o_IUhQxms6IPBKFzS9-yPoMVTsNCMO64T5m_5BXRYssgCyr3y1bw_xnKdfbMwJu4MYtO0Z8cOxGrOiPw-8oxjGWXpAfI5t52A_iTxbvyuftflPEgTXOZeU5a9ojFbST0Kwk6ylaIE2LyEnQsI-vsMyCgLDTCwJQsYohqfojLNN1wkI-T8EMUo0j79RhrRNJOenJjGS5-WCTR5S7GWVVqn8BmSh9B5zP2Iqpky0ylI2ajsfE4xUIFf61YU8bL8CY0IaEuj6FtWiYFeB8JncS34Tfqjc6nTBarXKWSqVgZK6hZRP9pBe0XA_Zrxqu-xZw_PCn8EoYfBbOn12q9vCPB4stYiQBVgSB_ZNtNnEhfq4lV6wNxJjERMA2jCMrQmiFcYEnK0nOhoIZdXz8I&l10n=ru&cts=1425023826472&mc=4.6439880450029385)
- [Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова](http://enc-dic.com/kuzhecov/Fanat-76339.html)